# How to unit test the asp.net scenario?

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing

I have a textbox and button in an aspx page. I enter some text in the textbox and click the button which will result in the text being printed in the browser.

How can i unit test this scenario like the way i unit test class library methods by creating test methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a "test.aspx" page and insert your code? that's typically how I seclude/test my code.

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) are two dotnet frameworks that allow you to do automated testing of asp.net web applications

Comment: @SilverNight: i tatally agree. but "textbox and button in an aspx page" are not unittests, too.  But these tests that can be done with "nunit"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you are trying to test your UI on a webapplication. As far as I know Visual Studio doesn't provide an appropriate way to do this. But there is this tool which is doing a good job:

http://seleniumhq.org/

The tool makes kind of a makro of the actions you have done on your website and repeats it if you want a thousand times.

Only downside is that it is not integrated in Visual Studio...

Greetings